# SQLite: Determining innings/sets of records inside database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently working with some baseball play by play data. My table `Outcomes` is

```
+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
| Date | HomeTeam | PlayNumber | AtBat | AtPitch | Outcome |
+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|14/03 |   HOU    |     1      |  HOU  |   TEX   |   SO    |
+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|14/03 |   HOU    |     2      |  HOU  |   TEX   |   SO    |
+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|14/03 |   HOU    |     3      |  HOU  |   TEX   |  GB OUT |
+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|14/03 |   HOU    |     4      |  TEX  |   HOU   |   HR    |
+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
| ...  |   ...    |    ...     |  ...  |   ...   |   ...   |
```

I also have a table `InningScore` that for each `Date` and `HomeTeam` has the total runs scored after each inning.

```
+------+----------+--------+-------+------+
| Date | HomeTeam | Inning | AtBat | Runs |
+------+----------+--------+-------+------+
|14/03 |   HOU    |   1    |  HOU  |  0   |
+------+----------+--------+-------+------+
|14/03 |   HOU    |   1    |  TEX  |  1   |
+------+----------+--------+-------+------+
| ...  |   ...    |  ...   |  ...  | ...  |
```

What I want to do is create a table with all information in `Outcomes` with a column appended that has the total runs scored in the inning `TRSI` e.g. if there were 3 runs scored in an inning, all plays in that inning would have `TRSI = 3`.

This could normally be accomplished with a simple join, but the problem is the plays in `Outcomes` do not have an inning reference. It is however possible to find where the innings begin and end by observing when the `AtBat` column changes.

In this circumstance, what is the best way to accomplish my result?

Comment: So you mean to say you want to get data based on the same set of `Date`, `HomeTeam` and `AtBat`?

Comment: Well `Date`, `HomeTeam`, `AtBat` and `Inning` but `Inning` is not an explicit field in the table `Outcomes`.

Comment: How about you do a join on the tables based on the `Date`, `HomeTeam` and `AtBat` and then get the `sum(Runs)` `GROUP BY Date, HomeTeam, Innings`?

Comment: First, on an international forum, you shouldn't post a question about baseball and innings and assume that everyone knows the definition of an inning.  Second, is there a way you can change `Outcomes` to just assign the inning when it is created?

Comment: That's true Gordon, I normally try to abstract all my questions but I couldn't think of another physical circumstance with this problem occurring.